# Powermock java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, powermockito

I am writing a test with mocking a static class, TreeCacheClient. 
The dependency on test is (build.sbt, play framework):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "commons-lang" %"commons-lang" % "2.6",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.0",
  "org.apache.commons" %"commons-lang3" % "3.5",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1210",
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "23.0",
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4" % "1.7.3" %  Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-api-mockito2" % "1.7.3" %  Test,
  "com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.5.0"
)
```

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({CacheClient.class})
    public class TreeServiceImplTest {

        @Mock
        private Configuration mockConfig;

        @Mock
        private CacheApi mockCache;

        @Mock
        private JedisPool mockRedisTool;
        @Mock
        private SegTree mockSeqTree;

        private SegTreeService segTreeService;

        private static final String CACHE_KEY = "testkey";
        private static final String CHANNEL = "testchannel";
        private static final String BACKUP_FILE = "file.ser";

        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            segTreeService = new SegTreeServiceImpl(mockConfig, mockCache, mockRedisTool);
        }

        @Test
        public void testGetSegTree() throws Exception {

            when(mockConfig.getString(CONF_SEG_TREE_CACHE_KEY)).thenReturn(CACHE_KEY);
            when(mockConfig.getString(CONF_PUBLISHER_CHANNEL_NAME)).thenReturn(CHANNEL);
            when(mockConfig.getString(CONF_SEG_TREE_BACKUP_LOCATION)).thenReturn(BACKUP_FILE);

            when(mockCache.get(CACHE_KEY)).thenReturn(mockSeqTree);
            doNothing().when(mockCache).set(CACHE_KEY, mockSeqTree);

            mockStatic(TreeCacheClient.class);
            when(TreeCacheClient.deserialize(BACKUP_FILE)).thenReturn(null);
            SegTree tree = segTreeService.getSegTree();
            assertEquals(tree, mockSeqTree);
            verifyStatic(TreeCacheClient.class, Mockito.times(0));
        }
}
```

I expect the test with no errors.

But I always get:

> [error] Test   *.service.TreeServiceImplTest.testSubscribe failed:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnproxiedType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/powermock/reflect/internal/proxy/UnproxiedType;,
>   took 0.001 sec [error]     at
>   org.powermock.core.MockInvocation.init(MockInvocation.java:31) [error]
>   at org.powermock.core.MockInvocation.(MockInvocation.java:22)
>   [error]     at
>   org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:151)
>   [error]     at
>   org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:134)
>   [error]     at
>   *.service.TreeServiceImplTest.setUp(SegTreeServiceImplTest.java)

even tested with 1.7.1 or 1.7.0 powermock lib. I also tried with different version of mockito2 lib. Still having this error. Any idea?

Comment: see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962003/mockito-test-gives-no-such-method-error-when-run-as-junit-test-but-when-jars-are